# When debugging Blazor apps in Chrome, new browser window opens with extensions disabled - want new tab in existing window with extensions

Tags: visual-studio, blazor

When debugging a Blazor app in VS 2019 a new browser window opens with no extensions.

I need the extensions to interact with the site, and I want it opened in any existing browser window in a new tab rather than a new window too.

I previously fixed this problem on ASP.net MVC / Core apps by deselecting 'Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET' in options. That is still deselected but this is now happening in Blazor. That problem is all I can find solutions to on Google.

How can I cause Blazor debugging sessions to open in a new tab in an existing browser window where I can access the extensions?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2022:

`Debug` > [project name] `Debug Properties` > uncheck: `Launch browser`

You'll find the URL you'll need to visit manually directly below it, under `App URL`.

Comment: This means I need to manually paste a URL into a browser window I open myself. i don't want this - I want a new tab in an existing browser windows. Thx